# duckling module for rasa

Tags: config, rasa-nlu, duckling

I try to train my bot based on rasa_nlu.
Below is my config file and i have problems because entity like "next month" is recognized by ner_spacy to be something else than time data. I want this type of entity to be recognized only by duckling module.
Thanks

*language: "en"
project: "nav-os"
pipeline:
- name: "nlp_spacy"
  model: "en"
- name: "ner_spacy"
- name: "tokenizer_spacy"
- name: "intent_entity_featurizer_regex"
- name: "intent_featurizer_spacy"
- name: "ner_crf"
- name: "ner_synonyms"
- name: "intent_classifier_sklearn"
- name: "ner_duckling"
  dimensions:
  - "time"*

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude the dimension for spaCy by defining the ones you want to include like it is described in the [documentation](http://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/#spacyentityextractor).

Means you could configure the `spacy_ner` component like the following to only extract `PERSON` entities (just as example).

```
pipeline:
- name: "SpacyEntityExtractor"
  # dimensions to extract
  dimensions: ["PERSON"]
```